# QT file open does not create a file

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

i am trying to use QT to open a file and write to it:

```
void fileClass::saver(QList<ToDo *> t, QList<appointment *> a, QString fileName)
{
    fileName.append(".mca");
    file = new QFile(fileName);
    if( !file->open(stdin,QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        qDebug() << "Could not create file " << fileName << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.count(); i++)
    {
        file->write(t[i]->ShowDate().toString().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(t[i]->ShowDate().toString().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(t[i]->ShowDescription().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(t[i]->ShowDescription().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(t[i]->ShowStart().toString().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(t[i]->ShowStart().toString().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(t[i]->ShowTitle().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(t[i]->ShowTitle().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(t[i]->ShowWarning().toString().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(t[i]->ShowWarning().toString().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(t[i]->ShowWarningTime().toString().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(t[i]->ShowWarningTime().toString().toAscii().constData()));
        switch (t[i]->ShowPriority())
        {
        case (VERY_HIGH):
            file->write("0\0");
            break;
        case (HIGH):
            file->write("1\0");
            break;
        case (NORMAL):
            file->write("2\0");
            break;
        case (LOW):
            file->write("3\0");
            break;
        case (VERY_LOW):
            file->write("4\0");
            break;
        }
        switch (t[i]->ShowState())
        {
        case (STILL_BEGIN):
            file->write("0\0");
            break;
        case (BEGUN):
            file->write("1\0");
            break;
        case (ALMOST_DONE):
            file->write("2\0");
            break;
        case (DONE):
            file->write("3\0");
            break;
        }
    }
    file->write("----------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i =0; i<a.count(); i++)
    {
        file->write(a[i]->ShowDate().toString().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(a[i]->ShowDate().toString().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(a[i]->ShowDescription().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(a[i]->ShowDescription().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(a[i]->ShowEnd().toString().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(a[i]->ShowEnd().toString().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(a[i]->ShowReminder().toString().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(a[i]->ShowReminder().toString().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(a[i]->ShowStart().toString().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(a[i]->ShowStart().toString().toAscii().constData()));
        file->write(a[i]->ShowTitle().toAscii().constData(), qstrlen(a[i]->ShowTitle().toAscii().constData()));
    }
    file->close();
}
```

yet the file does not get created somehow? any idea why? i made my own extension .mca ...

the filename is passes correctly without any trouble... and the debug is not shown, so in theory it should be working but no file is found in my folder...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it appears somwhere else then you expect. Do you use relative or absolute file path?

Comment: absolute, i get the filename using QT: QFileDialog::getSaveFileName

Comment: And you are sure that `saver` is called?

Comment: yeah, i discoverd that the arguments of open were wrong, i got it working now, thank you :)

Comment: Worth to mention: 1. You have memory leak each time saver is called 2. If you call toAscii you may lose encoding 3. You don't have to do constData(). QFile has write method that gets QByteArray and writes this byte array content to file (so no qstrlen needed)

Comment: To avoid the leak Kamil mentions, just create the QFile on the stack. No need for heap here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use another `QFile::open` method. A method you use opens existing file handle, so you open `stdin`. It doesn't matter what filename you set before.

Try this:

```
if( !file->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        qDebug() << "Could not create file " << fileName << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

This reference to stdin looks bogus:

```
   if( !file->open(stdin,QIODevice::WriteOnly))
```

`stdin` is for reading, not for writing.

Better use this form instead:

```
bool QFile::open ( OpenMode mode )
```

where `mode` would be `QIODevice::WriteOnly`